# Grandpa's Crazy Math II: Another Grandpa Mystery

Tags: lateral-thinking

Grandpa says: "This is really a stretch but

> Prove to me
>
> S = 0.5 or 1/2

Grandpa and his very lateral thinking!

Comment: Just out of curiosity : Rot13(Znl or vaireg vg naq fnl F.0 = F)

Comment: Clever but I am looking for 1/2

Comment: Could this have something to do with Shear Stress? Shear stress in fluids to be specific.

Comment: No @Abbas. Grandpa is not that engineering minded. Just crazy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe Grandpa starts with

> SIX = VI

and then (oh no no)

> $S = \frac{VI}{IX} = \frac{V}{X} = \frac{1}{2}$ (by treating the letters as products and cancelling the $\small I$'s).

A stretch - but Grandpa's been flexible before: [Why would five hundred and five be same as one?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/80821/19547)

Comment: Bulls Eye!  Great Lateral Thinking @Tom

Answer (score 5):

It is possible that Grandpa deduces his claim from

> The numbering on the models of the iPhone (listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone))
>  Explicitly, the iPhone numbering according to generation is as follows:
>  **1st** gen - iPhone
>  **2nd** gen - iPhone 3G
>  **3rd** gen - iPhone 3GS
>  **4th** gen - iPhone 4
>  **5th** gen - iPhone 4S
>  **6th** gen - iPhone 5 (and iPhone 5C)
>  **7th** gen - iPhone 5S
>  **8th** gen - iPhone 6 (and Plus)
>  **9th** gen - iPhone 6S (and Plus)
>  **10th** gen - iPhone 7
>  If Grandpa were to reasonably assume that the model numbering up to this point follows an arithmetic progression, then it would be fair to say that $S$ represents $0.5$ or, indeed, $\frac{1}{2}$. That is, for example, iPhone 5S is really iPhone 5.5
>  Of course, the progression is broken in the next generation with iPhone 8 but the argument can still be made that if an intermediate version between iPhone $N$ and iPhone $(N+1)$ is constructed then it takes on the numbering scheme iPhone $NS$ which we can reasonably assume to be equivalent to iPhone $(N+\frac{1}{2})$ as it claims a generational position of its own without bias towards its predecessor or descendant.